# Wordpress: Outputting code if is_page_template is true

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this code to output a different piece of code in the header depending on which page template I am using. But I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

I basically want to output:

`<div class="background-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">&nbsp;</div>` if someone is viewing the page template `header-hero.php`.

Whenever I do it I get this output on the page:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'is_page_template' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in /Users/Marc/Documents/Websites/www.psy-chosexualsomatics.dev/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/header.php on line 33`

```
<header class="header clear" role="banner">
            <?php function check_template() {if is_page_template( 'header-hero.php' ) {
                if ( ! is_page() ) {
                    echo "<div class='background-image' style='background-image: url('" . $image[0]; "'&nbsp;</div>";
                } } } ?>
                <div class="nav_container"> <!-- logo & nav -->
                <div class="logo col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                        <!-- svg logo - toddmotto.com/mastering-svg-use-for-a-retina-web-fallbacks-with-png-script -->
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/PST_LOGO_SHORT_T-1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-7">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <nav class="nav col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2" role="navigation">
                    <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
                </nav>

                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>

        </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put `is_page_template( 'header-hero.php')` into `()` which error message clearly states.

```
<header class="header clear" role="banner">
    <?php

    function check_template()
    {
        if (is_page_template('header-hero.php'))
        {
            if (!is_page())
            {
                echo "<div class='background-image' style='background-image: url('" . $image[0];
                "'&nbsp;</div>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="nav_container"> <!-- logo & nav -->
        <div class="logo col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <!-- svg logo - toddmotto.com/mastering-svg-use-for-a-retina-web-fallbacks-with-png-script -->
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/PST_LOGO_SHORT_T-1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-7">
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav class="nav col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2" role="navigation">
<?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
        </nav>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```